# How do I place a header within the 1inch margin? Here is my code:

Tags: header-footer, margins

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
            \newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw,dashed, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{multicol}


\textwidth=15cm \hoffset=-1.2cm %
\textheight=25cm \voffset=-2cm %

\pagestyle{empty} %

\date{} %

\def\keywords#1{\begin{center}{\bf Keywords}\\{#1}\end{center}} %



% Please, do not change any of the above lines


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Proposed Plan for Completing the Dissertation}
\lhead{Daniela \v{C}ulinovi\'c}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you currently see as the output?

Comment: a document without a header

Comment: What about adding `includeheadfoot` to your [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) settings?